# Is it possible to extract the second word in a string in liquid?

Tags: liquid

*I have a site ([dsgnjbs.com](http://dsgnjbs.com)), that displays a list of tweets. It uses the Liquid templating language. Changes in the Twitter API mean I can no longer auto-tweet with @mentions, which is causing some formatting errors. So:*

I need to extract the 2nd word of each tweet and set it as a variable. I know liquid has various ways it can process text, such as

```
{{ tweet.text | twitter_autolink | remove_first: 'On' | remove_first: '@' | remove: ':' | remove: '#design' | remove: '#job' }}
```

But is it possible to specifically target the second word of a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the "split" function.

```
{% assign words = tweet.text | split: ' ' %}
{{ words[1] }}
```

This gives you the second word, assuming that you use a space as a word separator.
See http://wiki.shopify.com/Split

Comment: Excellent, spent ages trying to work out how to evaluate an expression and check it with an IF statement.  Thanks!